# Django with MySQL: OperationalError (1054, "Unknown column '' in 'where clause'") when trying to query over Many-To-Many relationship

Tags: python, mysql, django

I realise that there are many previous questions with similar titles, however they are in a different context. I have not been able to find an answer that relates to Django and my particular situation.

I have a Many-To-Many relationship between 2 models in Django, as shown below:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Course(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UsersTakeCourses')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 1024)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class UsersTakeCourses(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mark = models.IntegerField()
```

In Django's views.py, given a username, I want to query the database in order to retrieve all of the courses that particular user is taking. This is my view method:

```
def my_courses(request, user_name):
    current_user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
    current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(users__pk=current_user.pk)

    context_dict = {'user_courses': current_user_courses}
    return render(request, 'FAProject_app/my_courses.html', context_dict)
```

However, when I run the server and try to load the page this view relates to, I get the following error message:

> OperationalError at /firstaid/my-courses/testuser/ (1054, "Unknown
>   column 'FAProject_app_userstakecourses.user_id' in 'where clause'")

I realise this is probably a syntax error in the mySQL query, however I don't know that would happen as Django builds the query itself.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually solved the issue. It was due to the fact that I had an unnecessary User table who's only purpose was to link one-to-one with the auth_user table. I removed this and changed my many to many to fetch the username straight from the auth_user table.

Comment: Good that you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here

```
current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(users__pk=current_user.pk)
```

Try instead

[Old]

```
current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(users__in=[current_user])
```

[Now]

```
current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(users__user=current_user)
```

Because in many to many relationships this creates new mapping table and that doesn't have direct many to many field.

Comment: Thank you for our reply. I changed the line to what you suggested and now I have this error: ValueError at /firstaid/my-courses/testuser/
Cannot query "testuser": Must be "User" instance.

Comment: Now I get this error: OperationalError at /firstaid/my-courses/testuser/
(1054, "Unknown column 'FAProject_app_userstakecourses.user_id' in 'where clause'")

Comment: Have you forgot to run make migrations and migrate commands? Check your table that column is exists or not. in mapping table.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an intermediate table for manytomany field. You should get user courses by that intermediate table. An easy way to do this is by using `related_name` like this.

```
class UsersTakeCourses(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_courses')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='courses_taken_by_users')
    mark = models.IntegerField()
```

When you are managing `user` and `course` relationship in this table, you do not need `users` in `Course` table. You can get courses taken by a user  like this.

```
current_user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
current_user_courses_id = current_user.user_courses.all().values_list('course', flat=True)
current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(id__in=current_user_courses_id)
```

or

```
current_user = User.objects.get(username=user_name)
current_user_courses_id = UsersTakeCourses.objects.filter(user=current_user).values_list('course', flat=True)
current_user_courses = Course.objects.filter(id__in=current_user_courses_id)
```

Comment: I get this error from the second line of code you wrote: AttributeError at /firstaid/my-courses/testuser/
'User' object has no attribute 'user_courses'

Comment: you need to change your models as I mentioned and run migrations.

Comment: I did change the models and run the migrations.

Comment: what is your `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: I think it is just the standard auth user with a username and a password.

Comment: try second method that I have posted.